# The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

The above error message is being thrown when I try to add a task to a queue. Here is my setup and the info about this problem:

- Project ID: `my-project`
- Service Account ID: `my-service-account`
- Task Queue Name: `my-queue`
- Task Queue Location: `asia-northeast1` (one of the few locations where Cloud Task is currently in beta)

Also, let's confirm that all the above exist and are running.

When I check my service account roles by POSTING to `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:getIamPolicy`

I receive a response similar to:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data":
    {
        "version": 1,
        "etag": "BwV6nNWJg4E=",
        "bindings": [
        {
            "role": "roles/cloudtasks.admin",
            "members": [
                "serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "roles/cloudtasks.enqueuer",
            "members": [
                "serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

As you can see, `my-service-account` has the following 2 roles:

1. roles/cloudtasks.admin
2. roles/cloudtasks.enqueuer

Both of those roles have the `cloudtasks.tasks.create` permission baked in.

When I try to add a task to the Cloud Task using the following:

POST `https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/v2beta3/projects/my-project/locations/asia-northeast1/queues/my-queue/tasks` + task payload

I receive the following error message:

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "data":
    {
        "error":
        {
            "code": 403,
            "message": "The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission \"cloudtasks.tasks.create\" for the resource \"projects/my-project/locations/asia-northeast1/queues/my-queue\" (or the resource may not exist).",
            "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
        }
    }
}
```

This really puzzles me.

Is there anybody who knows what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue out of nowhere. My creds were working great, and with no code changes, this error started popping up. No solution on my side.

Comment: To fix this I had to blow up all the roles and then re-add them. The only thing that comes to my mind is that I change the roles on the console, and then I also used the API. I feel that updating the roles mixing the API and the console might have created that bug.

Comment: find with client_email is using this function you will find it in service.json go to cloud console IAM and click on add role .. give it admin role :D I know it might be a bit insecure but if it works then you can plan around some good role to improve security

Comment: You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269193/creating-google-cloud-task-in-a-firebase-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating Google Cloud Task in a firebase function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269193/creating-google-cloud-task-in-a-firebase-function)

Comment: Thanks @Frenchcooc but this did not fix my issue. Unless, I'm misunderstanding their solutions, this is the same as what I did above. My service account had all the documented roles. Eventually, I gave up on this using this architecture and moved on implementing something else.

Answer (score 2):

**First check which service account is used for calling the API. It looks that whatever makes API calls uses default service account that may not have proper permissions.**

Sometimes if you omit wchich service account has to be user in API call then default account will be used  and you may get [authenticated with credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#finding_credentials_automatically) that don't won't let you create tasks.

I recommend using [API keys to authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#finding_credentials_automatically) to rule out any confusion with which service account is being authenticated.

Very similar case was discussed (and solved) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394894/cloudtasks-createtask-fails-lacks-iam-permission-cloudtasks-tasks-create-ev).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had listed the wrong `queue.name` (i.e. not the fully-qualified name) in the request, which cause this weird API error.

I discovered this error after looking at the source code for the Node Cloud Tasks client:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/quickstart.js

Answer (score 1):

You can grant access to your service account with the following command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding {project} \
    --member=serviceAccount:{service-account-email} \
    --role=roles/cloudtasks.enqueuer
```

Notice that Google Cloud will take some minutes to apply this change (even if the cli returns, you will need to wait)

Answer (score 0):

I have no clues why that worked, but I blew out all the roles and then added them again and then it worked. Seems to be a bug on Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was providing the project ID in the cloud tasks resource block:

```
resource "google_cloud_tasks_queue" "configuration" {
  name     = var.cloud_tasks_queue_id
  location = var.region
  project  = var.project_id
}
```

I had the exact same problem giving me an authorization error, however, this worked for me.

Note: What's confusing is that the Terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_tasks_queue) describes the project_id attribute as optional...