# Firebase - lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.update"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

After implementing firebase function as below code, deploy failed.

```
generateDailyStat: functions.pubsub.schedule('every day 00:00').timeZone('Asia/Seoul').onRun(generateDailyStat),
```

Error messages are as below.

```
i  functions: creating Node.js 8 function generateDailyStat(us-central1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  pubsub: all necessary APIs are enabled

Error: HTTP Error: 403, The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.update" for the resource "projects/MY_PROJECT/locations/asia-northeast2/jobs/firebase-schedule-generateDailyStat-us-central1" (or the resource may not exist).
```

My account is 'owner' role, and I give owner role of cloudscheduler to firebase service account.  But still failed.

What did I miss?

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support directly for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I gave my user all the permissions that could be related to the cloud schedule, and I didn't understand why I was getting this error.
Finally, I realized that the region I was trying to deploy to europe-west4, and it seems that in this region, you cannot create a cloud scheduler; there is no option to create it in this region. But I got an error about the permission. (The cloud function was created without a problem)

I ran the same code in another region, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Searching about it, it seems that this error might be related to the fact that the permission `cloudscheduler.jobs.update` - as per the documentation [Support level for permissions in custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support) - it's not supported for use yet, it's still in the `Testing` status, which means that some exceptions and errors are expected.

In another post on the community, a user informed that removing all the permissions and adding again, fixed the case "magically", so it might be an option for you to give a try. You can find more information on this solved case here:
[The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission “cloudtasks.tasks.create” for the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309804/the-principal-user-or-service-account-lacks-iam-permission-cloudtasks-tasks-c).

Let me know if the information clarified and helped you!

Comment: thanks for your answer.  As you mentioned, I tried remove and add again.  But it didn't fit for me. I'm still wonder I just using cron function as document mentioned, but why this is `Testing` status.

Comment: Hi @sungyong that's a good question. The only thing is that this confirms that errors might occur while using it since it's not fully operational yet. In case you want more information, the [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) might provide you more information.