# creating Google Cloud Task in a firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm getting an error in the firebase console functions log when calling a firebase HTTP function that tries to create a task.

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource "projects/my-gcloud-project-id/locations/us-central1/queues/myqueuename" (or the resource may not exist).

Maybe I'm confused between the gcloud id & location versus the firebase id & location?

EDIT: I have confirmed my location is us-central1 by running `gcloud --project my-gcloud-project-id tasks locations list`

Or maybe somehow I need to set up permissions?

My code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks')

const projectId = 'my-firebase-project-id';
const location = 'us-central1'
const queue = 'myqueuename'

exports.onFormSubmit = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
  const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath('my-gcloud-project-id', location, queue);

  const url = `https://google.com/` // edited for stack overflow
  const delaySeconds = 5;
  console.log('delaying for ', delaySeconds, ' seconds');

  const task = {
      httpRequest: {
          httpMethod: 'POST',
          url,
          body: '',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
      },
      scheduleTime: {
          seconds: delaySeconds
      }
  }

  const [ response ] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })

  console.log('task name', response.name);
});
```

Comment: this might help https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-and-cloud-tasks/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to create a Google Task you have to add the correct [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference-access-control) on IAM, in this  case as the error message is showing, you have to add the `cloudtasks.tasks.create` permission to the service account that is invoking the Cloud Function.

This can be done by going inside the Cloud Console and then into IAM, search for the service account [usually](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) is something like `service-project-number@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` (*update*: it was `my-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) and add the required permission, if you have a role based permissions `Cloud Tasks Enqueuer` should be enough to create the tasks.

Comment: Thanks, I added that role to my gcf-admin-robot service account, and still get the same error. Any idea how I can diagnose if this is still a permissions issue versus me not having the cloud task queue resource name correct?

Comment: I tried using https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter with //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/my-gcloud-project-id and cloudtasks.tasks.create and got a green checkmark: access granted. So maybe somehow I'm specifying the resource name wrong?

Comment: Both are possible, the best approach is to review all the service accounts that are being [used from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) and add the role `Cloud Tasks Enqueuer`, You can view all service accounts associated with your project in the [Service accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts) tab of your settings > Project Settings in the Firebase console.

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel! Following up here, my problem ended up being that I had two google cloud projects with similar names and I was getting confused between them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305239/google-cloud-policy-troubleshooter-says-service-account-doesnt-have-permissions

Comment: Thank you for the follow up @astromme, could you add which was the sanitized name of the SA that you added the permissions?

Comment: I added the permissions to my-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 0):

To get tasks working from a function, you need to add four roles to the firebase-adminsdk-*****@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com Principal: Cloud Functions Admin, Cloud Tasks Admin, Cloud Tasks Queue Admin and Service Account User. Anything short of those four roles and triggering a task function from another function will not work. Technically you could add just the Editor role, but that adds way more permissions than needed.

Google's documentation on this is a disaster.