# Google Cloud Policy Troubleshooter says service account doesn't have permissions despite being assigned in IAM

Tags: google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I have added the role "Cloud Tasks Enqueuer" to my project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com service account (see first screenshot). However, when I try and check if the account has permission to call "cloudtasks.tasks.create" it says that the service account lacks the cloudtasks.enquerer role (second screenshot). What is going wrong?

(note: I am adding this role to try and solve my other question, [creating Google Cloud Task in a firebase function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269193/creating-google-cloud-task-in-a-firebase-function))

[image: service account shows role Cloud Tasks Enqueuer]
[image: debugger shows no permission]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, turned out that I had two projects with similar names, and I got confused. The firebase project was `project-prod` created through firebase, and the google cloud project was `project` created through google cloud.

Therefore, I granted permissions to the correct service account but for the wrong project. The debugger was working correctly!

Comment: Nice you found it. Could you please accept your answer? Maybe other members can face this issue and can solve their issue the same way.

Comment: Yes! I have another 24 hours until I can accept my own answer, but will do @JossBaron